# .htaccess redirect is sending whole string, instead of partial

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I partially have my .htaccess rule working. What I have currently is:

```
#tag to search redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/tag\/*
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.testurl.co.uk/search-results?hsf=$1&id=12 [R=301,L]
```

What is currently happening, is where the $1 is, the entire of tag/* is going in there.

i.e request is tag/test URL generated is

https://www.testurl.co.uk/search-results?hsf=tag/test&id=12

when it should ideally be:

https://www.testurl.co.uk/search-results?hsf=test&id=12

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^tag/(.+)$ https://www.testurl.co.uk/search-results?hsf=$1&id=12 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Pattern `^tag/(.+)$` will capture any value after `/tag/` into group #1 and that is being used in `$1`.

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this.

Comment: Works brilliantly - and thank you for the explanation as to why it was not working. Many thanks :)